# How to verify $PA+A^tP=-I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
-2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$$

If $PA+A^tP=-I$, find the symmetric matrix $P$

in this question, how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do it by a very simple way: If $A = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
-2 & -3
\end{pmatrix}$ and $P = \begin{pmatrix}
 a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}$ then:

$$PA+A^tP = \begin{pmatrix}
 -4b & a-2c-3b\\
a-2c-3b & 2b-6c
\end{pmatrix}$$ which sould be equal to $-I = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: tnx was a good help. by the way. If I wanna approach using diagonalizing A, have any idea for method?

Comment: I don't think diagonalizing $A$ would be a good approach. Instead, consider using Kronecker product.